# Basis, dense subset and an inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V \subset H$, where $V$ is separable in the Hilbert space $H$.
So there is a basis $w_i$ in $V$ such that, for each $m$, $w_1, ..., w_m$ are linearly independent and the finite linear combinations are dense in $V$.

Let $y \in H$, and define $y_m = \sum_{i=1}^m a_{im}w_i$ such that $y_m \to y$ in $H$ as $m \to \infty$.

Then, why is it true that $\lVert y_m \rVert_H \leq C\lVert y \rVert_H$?

I think if the $w_i$ were orthonormal this is true, but they're not. So how to prove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplifying calculations, we can assume that $w_m$ is an orthonormal basis, by the following argument:

By the Gram-Shmidt orthogonalization process we can define $v_m$ out of the $w_1,..,w_m$'s, such that $v_1,..v_m$ is an *orthonormal* basis of $\langle w_1,..,w_m\rangle$. Then rewriting the coordinates accordingly, we have
$$y_m=\sum_{i\le m} b_{i(m)} v_i $$
Then, $||y_m||^2=\sum_{i\le m}(b_{i(m)})^2$, and, using the continuity of $x\mapsto \langle x,v_i\rangle$, we see that $b_{i(m)}$ tends to $\langle y,v_i\rangle=:b_i$ as $m\to\infty$, and that
$$||y||^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty {b_i}^2.$$
But maybe all these are not needed for your inequality, all is needed that the scalar product is continuous, and hence so is the norm, so
$$||y_m||\to ||y||$$
From which, if $y\ne 0$, the sequence $\displaystyle\frac{||y_m||}{||y||}$ convergences (to 1), hence bounded.

Well, if $y$ happens to be $0$, then the claim can also be *false*.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Choose $y=0$ and $a_{1,m} = \frac{1}{m}$. Then $y_m \to y$, but it is never the case that $\|y_m\| \leq C \|y\|$.

**Elaboration**:
This is because $\|y_m\| = \frac{1}{m} \|w_1\|$, the $w_i$ are linearly independent, hence non-zero. Hence $\|y_m\| = \frac{1}{m} \|w_1\| > 0$ for all $m$. There is **no** choice of $C$ that will satisfy the equation $\|y_m\| \leq C \|y\|$.

The above is true even if $w_i$ are orthonormal.

(I think you need to be more explicit about your choice of $a_{im}$. A 'nice' choice would be to let $y_m$ be the closest point to $y$ in $\text{sp}\{w_i\}_{i=1}^m$. This is what the first part of the answer by Berci does below.)

Comment: Is the inequality with the $\leq$ replaced with $\geq$ always true?

Comment: Yes, trivially, with $C=0$. For $C>0$ it has no chance in this generality, as any $y_m$ may be $0$.

Comment: But, it is true with $\le$, assuming $y\ne 0$. See the 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: No, it is never true, regardless of the choice of $C$. $C=0$ does not work for any $m$, and I am not sure what you mean by 'it is true with $\leq$'.

Comment: @copper.hat Berci says my original question is true for non-zero $y$. This seems correct to me as in parabolic PDEs people use this for the Galerkin method.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you are trying to figure out. Any sequence that converges is bounded, so if the limit is non zero, you can always find a constant so that the equation holds for a particular sequence. This is a property of **any** sequence converging to a non-zero limit. But if you have a prescribed method for choosing the $a_{im}$ as a function of $y$ (such as Gram-Schmidt, or Galerkin discretization) then you need to say something about how the $a_{im}$ are computed (or at least, some properties of the mapping) if you want to conclude $\|y_m\|\leq C \|y\|$ in general.

Comment: Maybe this explains what I am getting at: In general you are choosing $y_m \in W_m =\text{sp}\{w_1,...,w_m\}$. For any finite set of indices I can choose $y_m $ arbitrarily in $W_m$ without affecting convergence. So, given any $C$, I can choose $y_1$ so that $\|y_1\|$ is arbitrarily large and violates the inequality (if the limit is non-zero, and $C$ is independent of $y$).

Comment: One last gasp: The Galerkin discretization has conditions on a bilinear form that correspond, roughly, to saying that the $y_m$ is 'close' to an orthogonal projection on to the $\text{sp}\{w_1,...,w_m\}$. This is what allows one to conclude the existence of such a $C$ in this case.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for the explanation. In this case, $y$ should be $y_0$, a given initial condition, and $y_m$ as in my question is really $y_m(0)$ where $y_m$ satifies the approximating pde or whatever that thing the Galerkin method gives you is called. The book I am reading does not give an explanation as to how close anything is to any span so it was confusing.